Confusion on the proof of the transitivity of Big-O

This proof comes from Rosen's Discrete Math Textbook. It talks about how if $f(x) = O(g(x))$ and $g(x) = O(h(x))$, then $f(x) = O(h(x))$. My confusion is with the constants $C_1, C_2$, where how would the inequalities still hold if $C_1$ and $C_2$ were negative or different signs for example?
Kindly please let me know.

The constants have to be positive. The definition you cite does not mention it, but it’s a consequence of $\vert f(x)\vert\leq C_1\vert g(x)\vert$.

@SimonPitte Kindly could you elaborate how? It's not entirely obvious for me.

The $C_1,C_2$ will never be negative. Notice that, in the statement
$$
|f(x)| \le C_1 |g(x)|
$$
because of the absolute values $|f(x)|\ge 0$ and $|g(x)|\ge 0$. So the inequality would never make sense (beyond very narrow, trivial cases) if $C_1 < 0$. Similar for $C_2$ and $g,h$.
